# Azure DevOps - Should you explicitly pass variable(s) (groups) to templates or not?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

This afternoon I have been eagerly searching the web to find out whether variables/variable groups should be explicitly passed to a template (e.g. as parameters) or whether they are automatically inherited. Unfortunately, I found very conflicting information. I tried experimenting myself, but I could not get it to work.

Consider the following example given that variable group `commonGroup` contains a variable `varC` and variable group `stageGroup` contains a variable `varD`:

```
# azure-pipelines.yml
variables:
  - group: commonGroup
  - name: varA
    value: 'amazing value'

jobs:
- job: callTemplate
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  variables:
    - group: stageGroup
    - name: varB
      value: 'awesome value'
  steps:
  - template: path/to/your/template.yml
```

.

```
# template.yml

steps:
- script: |
    echo "Variable A: $(varA)"
    echo "Variable B: $(varB)"
    echo "Group variable C: $(varC)"
    echo "Group variable D: $(varD)"
```

Should this work as it is? If not, how would I make it so my script is able to access and echo all variables?

Comment: Because of the opaqueness of template compilation and variable resolution, I generally prefer being explicit with defining and passing typed parameters, rather than relying on template consumers having defined variables in the appropriate scope *outside* of the template. I consider it to programming in a strongly-typed language like C#, where you want methods to have clearly defined inputs and outputs and have minimal side effects. I don't want a template to only function properly if the consumer knew in advance what variables to define with no indication from the template what it requires.

Answer (score 1):

> Should this work as it is? If not, how would I make it so my script is able to access and echo all variables?

I tested the yaml you shared and found it can echo all variables without problem.

[image]

In Azure DevOps, variables and variable groups are automatically inherited by templates. If a variable or variable group is defined in a pipeline, it can be accessed within a template without needing to be explicitly passed as a parameter. If your pipeline and templates are simple and straightforward, automatic inheritance might be sufficient. The variables you define in your pipeline will be available in your templates.

However, it can often be beneficial to explicitly define and pass parameters to templates. This provides clarity about what data the template expects and helps prevent errors. It can make your pipeline easier to understand and maintain. You can refer [Template parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/template-parameters?view=azure-devops) for more information.

For example:

```
# azure-pipelines.yml
variables:
  - group: commonGroup
  - name: varA
    value: 'amazing varA'

jobs:
- job: callTemplate
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  variables:
    - group: stageGroup
    - name: varB
      value: 'awesome varB'
  steps:
  - template: template1.yml
    parameters:              
      varA: '$(varA)'
      varB: '$(varB)'
      varC: '$(varC)'
      varD: '$(varD)'
```

.

```
# template1.yml
parameters:
- name: varA
  type: string
- name: varB
  type: string
- name: varC
  type: string
- name: varD
  type: string

steps:
- script: |
    echo "Variable A: ${{ parameters.varA}}"
    echo "Variable B: ${{ parameters.varB}}"
    echo "Group variable C: ${{ parameters.varC}}"
    echo "Group variable D: ${{ parameters.varD}}"
```

Therefore, whether to rely on automatic inheritance or explicit passing depends on the specifics of your pipeline and templates, and which one is more convenient for you and your team.

Answer (score 0):

Not, you should not. You are using `Includes templates` approach: [Template usage reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops&pivots=templates-includes)

> **Includes templates** let you insert reusable content with a template. If
> a template is used to include content, it functions like an include
> directive in many programming languages. Content from one file is
> inserted into another file.

In this case, your resulting yaml will be like this:

```
# azure-pipelines.yml
variables:
  - group: commonGroup
  - name: varA
    value: 'amazing value'

jobs:
- job: callTemplate
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  variables:
    - group: stageGroup
    - name: varB
      value: 'awesome value'
  steps:
  - script: |
      echo "Variable A: $(varA)"
      echo "Variable B: $(varB)"
      echo "Group variable C: $(varC)"
      echo "Group variable D: $(varD)"
```